# amChart not rendering in Laravel Blade file

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, amcharts

I am new amchart and trying to display visualization in my Laravel (PHP Framework) project. In the same chartJs is getting display. But AmChart is not working.

Below is `chart.blade.php` for visualization page.

```
  <!-- AmCharts Resources -->
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
     <h6>AmChart</h6>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
     <canvas id="chartdiv" width="341" height="253" style="display: block; width: 341px; height: 253px;">/canvas>
   </div>
</div>



 <script src="{{URL::asset('js/charts/demo.js')}}"></script>

</body>
```

`js/charts/demo.js` is

```
// Create chart instance in one go
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

// Create pie series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
series.dataFields.value = "litres";
series.dataFields.category = "country";

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "litres": 301.9
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139.9
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 128.3
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 50
}];

// And, for a good measure, let's add a legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

console.log(chart.data);
```

> I am getting JSON data on console log from Chrome.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<canvas id="chartdiv"></canvas>` with `<div id="chartdiv"></div>`